# How to check the calling route name in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, routes, flutter-navigation

I am designing an application in which the same page A which is called from two different pages B and C. Page  B is passing an object and page C passing a list to A. I want to check whether A is called from B or C and also manage the different types of arguments passed from screen B and C? It's soo confusing. I am stuck

```
class A extends StatefulWidget {
  final List<Exercises> data;

  A({
    Key key,
    @required this.data,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _A createState() => _B();
}
```

from page B

```
onTap: () {
           Navigator.pushNamed(context,'/ExerciseScreen',
                              arguments: {text:'abcd',
                                          description:'I am description'});
 },
```

from page C

```
List<Class> data;  //its already filled

Navigator.pushNamed(
              context, '/ExerciseScreen',arguments: data
          );
```

If you want I can attach my router file too

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my opinion the architecture doesn't seem correct. But if this is the only way then you can do it using one of the below solutions:

1. If you care about data more than who has called class `A` then have two different arguments in class `A`, one for `Object` and one for `List`. If object is not null then work on object and if the list is not null then work on the list.
2. If you care about who has called class `A` then simply have another argument in `A` that would be source. When `B` is calling `A` pass `source` as `b` and if `C` is calling `A` then pass `source` as `c`

**Note**: you can use both solutions together as well.

**PS**: If you could explain in detail what is A,B and C then I can suggest a better architecture.

Comment: B is my home screen which has a UI consisting of a button and some other widgets. The button selects 5 random items from the list and passes it on to the next screen i.e A. and C is my screen consisting of  ListView which when clicked passed that item data to screen A. In short Screen B is passing Whole list and screen C is just passing one item.

Comment: You can create two different views, one which takes list of items and one which takes only one item.

Or with current screens you can pass List from `C` with only one item in it.

Answer (score 1):

Always pass data as a dynamic value Map

```
arguments = {'dataFromB':{text:'abcd',description:'I am description'}}

arguments = {'dataFromC': dataList}
```

in A just check the data like this

```
arguments.contains('dataFromB') //you know its called from B

arguments.contains('dataFromC') //you know its called from C
```

after access the data from the Map to process